# Mapbox JS : 2 Overlays (images) at same time

Tags: maps, mapbox, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

I cannot seem to get 2 image overlays on a map at the same time using a basic map. I do not see anything wrong with the code after 3 hours, and something so simple is driving me crazy. What am I missing here?

The first image overlay (a big one in the Northeast US) works perfectly fine as an overlay - but the 2nd one does not show up. (The second one should be overlaid on the national weather service office at the airport in New Braunfels, TX - it is small. But the overlay can be anywhere, I just need to understand how to get 2 overlays on at once when the page loads.) Edit : The source "secondimage" here is not loading when the map loads, but is not causing the map to not start or anything, the image just isn't there.

The code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Add an image</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#TL {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='TL'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZm9ybXVsYTQiLCJhIjoiY2lzNWl5N3RpMDNhYTNvcDFvNGVrZmZheCJ9.2X-n4Yk2XyxYqoPbP_IMnQ';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'TL',
maxZoom: 19,
minZoom: 1,
zoom: 5,
center: [-98.0284, 29.7039], 
style: 'mapbox://styles/formula4/cjifi4wp72stq2qp6p4ud3bt9'
});




map.on('load', function() {
map.addSource("firstimage", {
"type": "image",
"url": "kewx.gif",
"coordinates": [
[-80.425, 46.437],
[-71.516, 46.437],
[-71.516, 37.936],
[-80.425, 37.936]
]
});


map.addLayer({
"id": "overlay",
"source": "firstimage",
"type": "raster",
"paint": {
"raster-opacity": 0.85
}
});





map.addSource("secondimage", {"type": "image",
"url": "secondimage.gif",
"coordinates": [
[-98.0387, 29.7125], 
[-98.0182, 29.7125],  
[-98.0387, 29.6927], 
[-98.0387, 29.6920]  
]})



map.addLayer({
"id": "overlay",
"source": "secondimage",
"type": "raster",
"paint": {"raster-opacity": 0.85}
})






});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layer for the second image has the same ID as the first layer: `"id" : "overlay"`.

It has to be different from the first one, e.g.:

```
map.addLayer({
"id": "overlay_two",
"source": "secondimage",
"type": "raster",
"paint": {"raster-opacity": 0.85}
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so good with this in Google maps but I had to switch because the pricing is insane now. I voted your comment as useful but I am still new so I don't think it shows up.

Comment: Got it! I am just learning how things work here. You've helped me with that too. You actually answered 2 questions of mine and I can't thank you enough. Switching from Google to Mapbox has been a nightmare but I am getting better with javascript.